# How can I use history.push( ) and call a function at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, material-ui

I want to implement a button, in the AppBar provided by Material UI, that when clicked, it redirects me to a new page (from '/' to '/login'). So, I used history.push( ) and it works. But, the page does not render another component that it should display. The component is a function. How can I make this work?

I'm new to ReactJS and I'm using stuff from Material-UI so I don't how to tweak things to my favor.

It's a lot of code, so I made a working example for those who want to see what I mean:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/6jmlxlj3wz?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

In your `App.js` you are passing history to `Router` but you haven't imported it...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Login from './components/Login';
import history from './history'; // import it to use it

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <div className="App">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} /> // notice I also added exact
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And here is your `Home.js` cleaned up... (no need for the handleClick function...)

```
function gotoLogin() {
  history.push('/login');
}

function ContainedButtons(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
        className={classes.button}
        onClick={gotoLogin}
      >
        Login
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See a working demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/ovwrm11wl5

Comment: It's still not fully working for my whole app, but it does solve some of the problem, so thank you.

In my app, I actually implemented the login button in the AppBar provided by Material UI but when I try to implement it that in CodeSandBox, the button somehow don't show. So I code it as an individual button.

Comment: I've made edits to the question, I'm very sorry, I thought the fact that the button is in the AppBar doesn't matter.

Comment: @IrfanZainudin  if you want to use history you should import / use Router not BrowserRouter... so import { Router } from.... not import { BrowserRouter as Router }... These are 2 different things

Answer (score 0):

Use react-router-dom to manage your routes and for history.push functionality. Its support for React is built in so it will be a much more declarative coding experience for you.

Comment: Also another one  Reach router... same developer started both.

Comment: I am using react-router-dom, thank you for the input